# How can I pass a LIST<T> to as message to pubsub in c#

Tags: c#, publish-subscribe

Newbie programmer question here. I have a publisher code for pubsub in where I query from database and store the result in LIST in c#. Now I need to pass that LIST to pubsub topic as message. How can I achieve that?

```
var egv_data = do_cgmdata_query(conn); //query method
if (egv_data != null)
{
    while (egv_data.Read())
    {
        Participant_List_Data.Add(new Participant_Data()
        {
            fitbit_id = (string)egv_data[0],
            sf_candidate_id = (string)egv_data[1],
            egv = (string)egv_data[2],
            egv_datetimelocal = (string)egv_data[3]
        });
    }
    egv_data.Close();

    //publish a message to the topic
    foreach (Participant_Data aList in Participant_List_Data)
    {
        PubsubMessage message = new PubsubMessage
        {
            Data = aList /*need to pass this correctly to pubsub topic, aList.fitbit_id, aList.egv...etc*/
            Attributes = {
                {"version","1.0"}
            }
        };
        //publish the message to topic
        pub.Publish(topicName, new[] { message });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `PubsubMessage.Data` a `Participant_Data` type object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use C# generic in this case as below:-

create your class like this

```
public class PubsubMessage<T>
{
   public PubsubMessage(List<T> Data, Object someObject)// This object is just an example but replace it with some type or class in actual code
   {
   }
}
```

Then you can pass any type into the constructor. Go and study some topic on generic in C# you will get the idea